# How to change value of keyframe dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations, keyframe

I have the following code to move an image

```
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 40%;}
}
```

Now I need to change the value of left ie 40% using javascript how do i achieve this ?

Comment: For dynamic animations, it's better to use `transition`(e.g. `transition: left 0.5s;`) instead of `animation`, and set the `left` value directly via javascript.

Comment: can u give any reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the reference for using `transition`:

```js
document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('click', function() {
   // set the left value dynamically
   this.style.left = '40%';
});
```

```css
/* cosmetics, ignore these */
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: salmon;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

/* relevent styles */
.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">click me</div>
```

Comment: Thank you was looking for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `animate function` for transition of the div element. check the below example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box").click(function(){
    $("#box").animate({
        left: '40%'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  background: #98bf21;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you was looking for this :)

Comment: You are most welcome, if it's helpful please accept the answer. :)